# How it is possible to have a variable index in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried following example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int arr[a];
    arr[20] = 1;
    printf("%d", arr[20]);
}
```

output:

```
20
1
```

Comment: `a` can't be const if you intend to modify it.

Comment: Show the exact compilation command (and some [MCVE], with input and output). Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Tell what C standard do you want to follow. Look into some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site.

Comment: Read about [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s. You could (and in your example, you probably should) want to avoid them, and prefer [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) instead.

Comment: You can also define a pointer and allocate memory to pointer. It can be done as follows: int a=20; int *arr=new int[a];

Comment: @AnshuKumar: `new` is a C++ thing. The OP is learning C. Don't confuse him please!

Comment: See also [*How to Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking your next question on StackOverflow

Comment: Oops sorry, you may use malloc() to allocate memory

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by modifying a `const` variable. It would be fine if `a` were non-const, and you check validity before creating the array

Comment: If you entered '20' then 'arr[20]=1;' is and out-of-bounds access, and you have UB.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for a way to dynamically allocate memory for your array. Dynamically means that the memory to be used for your array is determined during the execution of your program. A very reasonable way to implement this is the usage of malloc and free which are part from the stdlib.h. Here is a very simple example which shows how to do that. (it also populates the array and afterward prints the array's elements)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *arr;

    printf("Enter the amount that you would like to allocate for your array: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    /* Dynamically Allocate memory for your array
        The memory is allocated at runtime -> during the execution
        of your program */
    arr = (int *)malloc(a * sizeof(int));
    /* Check if the memory was allocated successfully
       In case it wasn't indicate failure printing a message to
       the stderr stream */
    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to allocate memory!");
        return  (-1);
    }

    /* Populate the array  */
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    /* Print each element of the array */
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }

    /* Free the memory once you no longer need it*/
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is also a very detailed information on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Here is another way to allocate the required memory dynamically by the usage of a variable length array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void vla(int n);

int main()
{
    int a;

    printf("Enter the amount that you would like to allocate for your array: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    /*vla stands for Variable Length Array*/
    vla(a);

    return 0;
}

static void vla(int n)
{
    /*The correct amount of storage for arr is automatically
    allocated when the block containing the array is entered
    and the declaration of the arr is reached. This allows
    you to use variables for array index which are not compile-time constants*/
    int arr[n];

    /* Populate the array  */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    /* Print each element of the array */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }

    /*No need of using free since the storage is automatically
     deallocated when leaving the block*/
    return;
}
```

I would also advise to follow a consistent coding style in order to make your code easier to understand for you and other people. Here is a brief guide which contains the main rules on how to achieve that: https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/c-coding-style.html.en

Comment: Quite good answer, but you could improve it. First by mentioning [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s since the question has one, and also by using `perror` on failure of `malloc`

Comment: An easier to code, review and maintain alternate to `arr = (int *)malloc(a * sizeof(int));` is `arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * a);`